# Vertical-align with baseline and textareas

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to get a label lined up with the baseline of the first line of text in a text area.

The naive attempt:

```html
<div style="vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block">
   <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
</div>
<div style="vertical-align: baseline; display: inline-block">
   <textarea name="comments" id="comments">test</textarea>
</div>
```

results in the label being aligned with the bottom of the text area.  I'd prefer to have it lined up with the **first** line of the area.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the font sizes for the label and the textarea the same?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the textarea is viewed as a block, like an image. When doing a vertical-align, it is using the border to determine placement instead of the text. In the example below, you can see that the label and div are positioned based on the text inside, where the textarea behaves like the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/kenearley/nGaQs/3/

I think the only way to get the label and textarea to align the way you want is to do a vertical-align:top, then make sure your font-size and line-height ratio match up right.

Comment: And looking at it further, you can see that using baseline doesn't even work with two block level elements like the label and div. The label is lining up to the last line in the div.

Comment: When I try out your JSFiddle, it seems to me that the label and textarea line up, and the div and img do not.

Comment: Firefox displays the textarea as desired in this JSFiddle, Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `label` `div` inside of the same `div` as the textarea, then, if you want it set to the top of the `textarea` you're looking for `vertical-align: top`, not `baseline`.

View and example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/anhus/

Comment: The problem is that i want the text lined up on the baseline of the text in the textarea.  Aligning it to the top just for text areas looks wrong when you compare it to the rest of the label+text fields that are aligned with the baseline.

Comment: Okay, well just change `vertical-align:top` to what you want it to be. baseline, or whatever.

Comment: -1: misses the point. He wants to align the label baseline with the textarea's *first* baseline, which is the typographically correct thing. I still haven't found a good way to do this - it comes up whenever what you are labelling has different text metrics.

Answer (score 0):

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Comments: <textarea></textarea>
</label>
<hr>
```